# fopen(): no such file or directory when sending char pointer as the filename

Tags: c

I have searched for all the possible answers to this problem; however, I still get the error. I have a server.conf file it has some values and I assign the values in this file to variables in a structure. I want to use the path variable in the struct as the filename in fopen. I know this problem has been asked about several times, but I still couldn't recognize what's the problem after days.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *path;

} MainStruct;


int parse_config(MainStruct *inf)
{

    FILE *file;
    char *line = NULL;
    char *path;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    file = fopen("server.conf", "r");
    if (file != NULL)
    {

        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1)
        {

            if (strstr(line, "PATH") != NULL)
            {
            
                inf->path = strdup(line + 5);
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
        return 0;

    return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MainStruct val;

    parse_config(&val);
    char *pt = val.path;
    printf("%s", pt);
    FILE *fp = fopen(pt, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fopen() failed in file %s at line # %d \n", __FILE__,__LINE__);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fclose(fp);

}
```

this is the content of the server.conf file where I defined the PATH:

```
PATH file.html
```

I have checked the value of pt with `printf` and it's exactly the string file.html.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? It would help if you provide info about obvious things that anyone debugging the issue would want to know. For example, have you checked the value of `pt`? Is it the string value you expect? Is `file.html` in the same directory as you are running the executable from? etc.

Comment: The string will, essentially, be `"\"file.html\""`, and I doubt the file in the file-system really have the double-quotes. Remove the quotes in the `server.conf` file.

Comment: For future problems like this, please learn [how to *debug* your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Either by simply printing out the contents and values of variables, or by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: The line read by `getline(...)` will have a trailing newline character. You need to remove it.

Comment: @kaylum, yes I have checked the value of pt and it is exactly what I want, it is "file.html"

Comment: I have also removed all the trailing spaces using a trim function so be sure that pt is exactly the string I want

Comment: Quotes are only needed in the *source code*, not in the strings you read from file.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Note we do not need to see how you do `atoi`, so you may remove this from your example. Just read the `PATH` entry and open the file.

Comment: Note also that `perror("fopen()")` is not very informative. Include the file name you are trying to open in the message.

Comment: A [mcve] should include *all* the code needed to reproduce the problem. You only posted a fragment without `main` and without any necessary `#include` directives. Editing them out was a wasted effort. Make a single `.c` file, compile it, run it, verify that it does what you say it does, *then post the entire file, unedited*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man getline:

> `getline()`  reads  an  entire line from stream, storing the address of the buffer containing the text into `*lineptr.`  The buffer is null-terminated *and includes the newline character, if one was found*.

So your `path` is likely to point to a buffer that contains `file.html\n`, not `file.html`. It could be rather confusing if you `printf` it and don't pay attention to how many newlines are printed at the end.

Answer (score 2):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", strdup("PATH \"file.html\"" + 5));
}
// output: "file.html"
```

If the value of pt is `"file.html"` then the fopen() will try to open a file that is named `"file.html"` instead of a file named `file.html`.

Unless there is a file where the filename itself *includes the double quotes*,  fopen() will fail.

Edit: added example code

Comment: I removed the quotations from the server.conf file, but again I get the error no such file  or directory

Comment: Does `file.html` exist in the working directory where the binary is invoked?

Comment: yes, all the files are in the same directory.

Comment: that's a very bad example, you're leaking memory

Comment: @phuclv that is true, I kept it to a minimum to illustrate the point what `strdup` produces in this case. For the record: when using `strdup`, one should always make sure the allocated memory is free'd at some point.